# Error when importing SQL to ClearDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cleardb

I'm using MySQL.
I exported my db's tables to an sql file via phpMyAdmin.
I have no problems importing that file locally via phpMyAdmin, but when I try to import it to ClearDB MySQL I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
>   `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE' at line 4

Here's the SQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 06, 2017 at 10:39 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `repro`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `a`
--

CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `b`
--

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `v3` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `c`
--

CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v9` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `dId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `d`
--

CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `e`
--

CREATE TABLE `e` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `f`
--

CREATE TABLE `f` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `g`
--

CREATE TABLE `g` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_g_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `v9` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `h`
--

CREATE TABLE `h` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v10` text NOT NULL,
  `v11` text NOT NULL,
  `v12` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `i`
--

CREATE TABLE `i` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v13` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v14` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `v15` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `j`
--

CREATE TABLE `j` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v16` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v17` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v18` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v19` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v20` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v21` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `k`
--

CREATE TABLE `k` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v7` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `l`
--

CREATE TABLE `l` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_1e8337240143dcb523962f54c5f` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_5cac5f64c02f625546708887642` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ec5caf1853f876085f6977a042b` (`dId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `d`
--
ALTER TABLE `d`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a02b2b9446741ac1d591d286507` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_d7f5f5872631eba4c37b2de5714` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a951d4354f5f44bc2b548e979e2` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `f`
--
ALTER TABLE `f`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_98a6a31288ef0611a4281f8f668` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_266acd73ddba66293083c974056` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_e86962992225e0f868acdb3dea2` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ff9eacd300026082e7448badeb0` (`cId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_91e06a0a4cc1ccad997742ebbd9` (`kId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a4d7e49f417025c79fa0f5e46e0` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_080397f56230d7ef8fa7abe9a96` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_dfdbe5502a5ecc6a13c6216586c` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_0fa8bd5e1970550231a6dbf48f9` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_cd79170a5dddf791a53e9c4ce30` (`gId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_8b585eb0f2626cce64cacf47203` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f7ffaabf651b77f45d97c6c016d` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ac085218a218c0c95feb3ccced5` (`cId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f4b2c776c5615151c3d31cfd3f7` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_08bc80ed5a66c15c042a38bcbd0` (`iId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_4c1a4e27ee2b331ad2cacae0dcb` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f3a091a7e4c54ff96d394c207be` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f9785f8f284daf9e101b6cf298d` (`cId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `d`
--
ALTER TABLE `d`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `f`
--
ALTER TABLE `f`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_1e8337240143dcb523962f54c5f` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_5cac5f64c02f625546708887642` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ec5caf1853f876085f6977a042b` FOREIGN KEY (`dId`) REFERENCES `d` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a02b2b9446741ac1d591d286507` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a951d4354f5f44bc2b548e979e2` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_d7f5f5872631eba4c37b2de5714` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_98a6a31288ef0611a4281f8f668` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_266acd73ddba66293083c974056` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_91e06a0a4cc1ccad997742ebbd9` FOREIGN KEY (`kId`) REFERENCES `k` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_e86962992225e0f868acdb3dea2` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ff9eacd300026082e7448badeb0` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_080397f56230d7ef8fa7abe9a96` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a4d7e49f417025c79fa0f5e46e0` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_dfdbe5502a5ecc6a13c6216586c` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_0fa8bd5e1970550231a6dbf48f9` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_8b585eb0f2626cce64cacf47203` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cd79170a5dddf791a53e9c4ce30` FOREIGN KEY (`gId`) REFERENCES `g` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_08bc80ed5a66c15c042a38bcbd0` FOREIGN KEY (`iId`) REFERENCES `i` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ac085218a218c0c95feb3ccced5` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f4b2c776c5615151c3d31cfd3f7` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f7ffaabf651b77f45d97c6c016d` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_4c1a4e27ee2b331ad2cacae0dcb` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f3a091a7e4c54ff96d394c207be` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f9785f8f284daf9e101b6cf298d` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Here's the modified SQL after removing datetime variable length:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 06, 2017 at 10:39 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `repro`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `a`
--

CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `b`
--

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `v3` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `c`
--

CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v9` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `d`
--

CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `e`
--

CREATE TABLE `e` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `f`
--

CREATE TABLE `f` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `g`
--

CREATE TABLE `g` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_g_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v8` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `v9` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `h`
--

CREATE TABLE `h` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v10` text NOT NULL,
  `v11` text NOT NULL,
  `v12` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `i`
--

CREATE TABLE `i` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v13` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v14` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `v15` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `j`
--

CREATE TABLE `j` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v16` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v17` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v18` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v19` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v20` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v21` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `k`
--

CREATE TABLE `k` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v7` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `l`
--

CREATE TABLE `l` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v4` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `jId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_1e8337240143dcb523962f54c5f` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_5cac5f64c02f625546708887642` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ec5caf1853f876085f6977a042b` (`dId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `d`
--
ALTER TABLE `d`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a02b2b9446741ac1d591d286507` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_d7f5f5872631eba4c37b2de5714` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a951d4354f5f44bc2b548e979e2` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `f`
--
ALTER TABLE `f`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_98a6a31288ef0611a4281f8f668` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_266acd73ddba66293083c974056` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_e86962992225e0f868acdb3dea2` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ff9eacd300026082e7448badeb0` (`cId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_91e06a0a4cc1ccad997742ebbd9` (`kId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_a4d7e49f417025c79fa0f5e46e0` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_080397f56230d7ef8fa7abe9a96` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_dfdbe5502a5ecc6a13c6216586c` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_0fa8bd5e1970550231a6dbf48f9` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_cd79170a5dddf791a53e9c4ce30` (`gId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_8b585eb0f2626cce64cacf47203` (`cId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f7ffaabf651b77f45d97c6c016d` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_ac085218a218c0c95feb3ccced5` (`cId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f4b2c776c5615151c3d31cfd3f7` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_08bc80ed5a66c15c042a38bcbd0` (`iId`);

--
-- Indexes for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fk_4c1a4e27ee2b331ad2cacae0dcb` (`jId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f3a091a7e4c54ff96d394c207be` (`fId`),
  ADD KEY `fk_f9785f8f284daf9e101b6cf298d` (`cId`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `d`
--
ALTER TABLE `d`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `f`
--
ALTER TABLE `f`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `a`
--
ALTER TABLE `a`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_1e8337240143dcb523962f54c5f` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `b`
--
ALTER TABLE `b`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_5cac5f64c02f625546708887642` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `c`
--
ALTER TABLE `c`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ec5caf1853f876085f6977a042b` FOREIGN KEY (`dId`) REFERENCES `d` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `e`
--
ALTER TABLE `e`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a02b2b9446741ac1d591d286507` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a951d4354f5f44bc2b548e979e2` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_d7f5f5872631eba4c37b2de5714` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `g`
--
ALTER TABLE `g`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_98a6a31288ef0611a4281f8f668` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `h`
--
ALTER TABLE `h`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_266acd73ddba66293083c974056` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_91e06a0a4cc1ccad997742ebbd9` FOREIGN KEY (`kId`) REFERENCES `k` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_e86962992225e0f868acdb3dea2` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ff9eacd300026082e7448badeb0` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `i`
--
ALTER TABLE `i`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_080397f56230d7ef8fa7abe9a96` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_a4d7e49f417025c79fa0f5e46e0` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_dfdbe5502a5ecc6a13c6216586c` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `j`
--
ALTER TABLE `j`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_0fa8bd5e1970550231a6dbf48f9` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_8b585eb0f2626cce64cacf47203` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cd79170a5dddf791a53e9c4ce30` FOREIGN KEY (`gId`) REFERENCES `g` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `k`
--
ALTER TABLE `k`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_08bc80ed5a66c15c042a38bcbd0` FOREIGN KEY (`iId`) REFERENCES `i` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ac085218a218c0c95feb3ccced5` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f4b2c776c5615151c3d31cfd3f7` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f7ffaabf651b77f45d97c6c016d` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `l`
--
ALTER TABLE `l`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_4c1a4e27ee2b331ad2cacae0dcb` FOREIGN KEY (`jId`) REFERENCES `j` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f3a091a7e4c54ff96d394c207be` FOREIGN KEY (`fId`) REFERENCES `f` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_f9785f8f284daf9e101b6cf298d` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing the issue with ClearDB support:

The problem is that the relevant ClearDB clusters run mysql 5.5, while for mysql 5.6.5 and below the following applies:

"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is only acceptable on TIMESTAMP fields. DATETIME fields must be left either with a null default value, or no default value at all - default values must be a constant value, not the result of an expression."

Answer (score 0):

The data type `datetime` has no variable length. So remove the `(6)`

```
`v2` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Tried that already...

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=In' at line 4

Comment: Well you did not remove both `(6)`, did you?

Comment: Right sorry, removed now, got this error:
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 29: Invalid default value for 'v2'

Comment: Yeah, well, you have to correct it everywhere in your script. Come on. Put a little effort in this here.

Comment: I did... I'm always using replace all. I added the modified SQL to the topic, below the original SQL.

Comment: *Invalid default value for 'v2'* - Look where you define this column. Execute every command one by one and check which is failing.

Comment: Since line 29 is mentioned, it refers to that line:
`v2` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
as it's the only `v2` within that table. So that's the line that's failing. To back this up, when I remove this line - I get the following error: ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 41: Invalid default value for 'v2', which basically indicates the exact same error in an identical line in another table. In other words, I don't think there's a doubt that what's causing the error is: datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: I guess it should. Any idea why it doesn't? Possibly the issue is with ClearDB?